# Oracle APEX Interactive Report Not Updating

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report on a page in my application. I created a filter at the top of the dashboard that causes the whole page to refresh. Everything looks good but when I go to download the report it reverts the downloaded data back to the default date ranges. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the page refresh is refreshing your page item value too.

there are two options you can try.

1. Setting Session state on item change by executing the below code using dynamic action.

   BEGIN
   APEX_UTIL.set_session_state('P1_DEPTNO', 30);
   END;
2. Stop Refreshing the page